# MockedReturnValue causes useQuery to always return “undefined” for data on first render of react component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-query

I’m using React Testing Library and jest to test my next.js app. I am writing my unit test on the main parent component, which in-turn has children components within it.
In a jest test mockreturnValue is causing useQuery (used by the component being tested) to always return undefined for the data when the component is first rendered. Subsequent renders has the expected data.

Since,the first time useQuery it is returning undefined, child component is not getting loaded in the virtual DOM.

Any workaround for this?

Parent component

```
const parentComponent = () => {
const { data: childAQuery, isLoading: childALoading } = useQuery(
    ‘childA’,
    fetchChildAData,
    {
      staleTime: Infinity
    }
  );
console.log(childAQuery, ‘response from Query’)    // trying to print the response here, which  goes undefined on the initial render, but has values on subsequent render.//

return(
<>
<div>
{childAQuery?.results.length > 0 && (
<childAComponent {…{props}}
/>
}}
</div>
</>
)}
```

Api call

```
import axios from 'axios';
 export const fetchChildAData = async () => {
  let { data } = await axios.get('/api/childAdata’);
  data.results = covertTreeData(data.results);
  return data;
};
```

Test file

```
jest.mock("../../../src/queries/fetchChildAData"); // path where above api is defined
  describe(‘componentTesting’, ()=>{
beforeEach(()=> {
 fetchChildAData.mockReturnValue ({
data : {
results: [
{ id: “123test”,
Name: ‘ChildATest” }
]}
)}
})

it(‘render child A component’, async ()=>{ const {container} = render<parentComponent/>
 screen.debug().  // the virtual DOM does not render the child A component since useQuery returned undefined and hence childAQuery?.results.length > 0 check fails this component render//
 await expect(screen,findByText(‘ChildATest’).toBeInTheDocument();  }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm in the same situation and can't find a solution anywhere.